# Why can't I use the star operator like this? def foo(*args, this="default", **kwargs)

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, arguments, syntax-error

#### This would be fun:

```py
def foo(*args, this="default", **kwargs):
    pass
```

#### but

```py
  File "foo.py", line 1
    def foo(*args, this="default", **kwargs):
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Since I have an unknowable set of positional args, an unknowable set of keyword arguments, and one or two known keyword arguments, my other option is:

```py
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    this = kwargs.pop("this", "default")
    ...
```

So, since there always seems to be a good answer as to why things are the way they are, I would like to know. Why isn't this allowed?

---

EDIT:
Thanks @dano
[Added in Python3](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)

Comment: This is actually allowed in Python 3.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget Python 2.7.6

Comment: @dano: Thank you for confirming my thoughts. I was pretty sure it was a "not allowed in the grammar" argument, but I started to dig into the literature to make sure

Comment: @samstav what you *can* do is: `def foo(this="default", *args, **kwargs)` you can read more about it [here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/)

Comment: @alfasin Good suggestion, I didn't think about that. but not ideal, since the first positional argument given would become `this`.

Comment: @alfasin: Although you can't actually call this the way you want in a lot of circumstances, because you can't have non-keyword args after keyword args (so 'this' gets a default, but can't actually be named as 'this' by the caller)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do with `this` is make it a keyword-only argument; there's no way to provide as a positional argument. Support this feature was added in Python 3.0. [Here](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) is the PEP that describes its addition, as well as other related enhancements. It's rationale section describes the issue pretty clearly:

> The current Python function-calling paradigm allows arguments to
>     be specified either by position or by keyword.  An argument can be
>     filled in either explicitly by name, or implicitly by position.
>
> There are often cases where it is desirable for a function to take
>     a variable number of arguments.  The Python language supports this
>     using the 'varargs' syntax ('*name'), which specifies that any
>     'left over' arguments be passed into the varargs parameter as a
>     tuple.
>
> One limitation on this is that currently, all of the regular
>     argument slots must be filled before the vararg slot can be.
>
> This is not always desirable.  One can easily envision a function
>     which takes a variable number of arguments, but also takes one
>     or more 'options' in the form of keyword arguments.  Currently,
>     the only way to do this is to define both a varargs argument,
>     and a 'keywords' argument (**kwargs), and then manually extract
>     the desired keywords from the dictionary.

Basically, this was just a limitation of the original implementation of varargs, which didn't get addressed until Python 3.

Comment: Although the final adopted PEP actually would be portable into Python 2, as it doesn't change the behaviour of any existing code (assuming anyone was still agitating for Python 2.8, anyhow.. :-)).

Comment: @NickBastin Right. I'm not sure why it didn't get backported to 2.6, like a lot of other backwards compatible 3.0 changes.

Comment: A patch was written to backport it to 2.7, but apparently it was not included just because no one got around to it, and the powers that be wouldn't budge on either delaying 2.7 or making an additional 2.x release.  A real travesty.  See [this issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue1745) in the Python tracker.